# Cannot print variables onto the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, text, printing

I want to print variables onto the screen of my game.  I am using text boxes to display the variables. When I try update the text boxes, the text boxes are blank.

I use an EventListener to update the text boxes:

`// Add the EventListener that updates the game HUD
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateHUD);`

Here is the 'updateHUD()' function:

```
    public function updateHUD(event:Event) {

        txtHealth.text = String(player.pHealth);
        txtDarts.text = String(player.pAmmo);
        txtScore.text = String(player.pScore);
    }`
```

If I place 
            `txtScore.text = String("score");` within this code, not even "score" is printed.  The Text Box is still blank.

I was talking with a friend about this.  He said he had a similar issue in his project.  His problem had to do with incorrect Text Box settings.  The boxes I want to update are set to "Classic Text", "Dynamic Text," and "Singleline."

I have other text boxes that act as "labels." They are displayed just fine on the screen.  But I do not try to change them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Have you embedded the font for the dynamic textfield?

Are your textfields on the same level as your code or could they be held within a movieclip? e.g. someClip.txtHealth.text = "score";

Comment: have you tried to trace the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could be that you need to embed the font, and make sure that the text box is using that font.

if you don't know how to embed a font, you can either:

1. click on the text box and click embed in the properties box
2. go to `Text->Font Embedding`

then just choose the font you are using, choose the characters you want and press the plus button.

Edit: Also where exactly are you putting the `addEventListener` line? You may want to check that the event is ever being fired.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem! The values now print themselves onto the screen correctly. :)